# How to add the values from the image into the Mysql database table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mysql, database

I am working on code to tag images. I have the code to display the coordinates of the tag position on the image and it displays it on a small output screen. What is need is I want to get these values from the tag position and add them to the mysql database table.

The code that displays the coordinates from the image:

HTML:

```
 <div>
    <img src="fashion.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
          <input type="button" id="btnView" value="Display areas" class="actionOn" />
          <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" class="actionOn" />
          <input type="button" id="add" value="add areas" class="actionOn" />
 </div>
        <br>
        <div id="output" class='output'> </div>
```

javascript:

```
   function areaToString (area) {
    return (typeof area.id === "undefined" ? "" : (area.id + ": ")) + area.x + ':' + area.y  + ' ' + area.width + 'x' + area.height + '<br />'
  }

  function output (text) {
    $('#output').html(text);
  }

  // Log the quantity of selections
  function debugQtyAreas (event, id, areas) {
    console.log(areas.length + " areas", arguments);
  };

  // Display areas coordinates in a div
  function displayAreas (areas) {
    var text = "";
    $.each(areas, function (id, area) {
      text += areaToString(area);
    });
    output(text);
  };
```

the below image shows the display of the coordinates of the tag:

[image]

from the image when u can see the coordinates. what i want is when i press add areas button, the values must be added to the table .

The table :

[image]

Can someone help me how to get these values of the coordinates and add them to the table.

Comment: probably a web server could help

Comment: i would like to use mysql

Comment: How are you adding content to your MySQL Database currently? You will need to send the data to a Server Side Script that can then add the data to your Database.

Comment: @twisty currently I dont add anything to the database , i know that i should use sever side scripts but i dont know how to do it

Comment: @Uviiii this will not be the place to learn that. You will want to speak top your Web Server Host to see what Server Side scripting is supported, like PHP. Then you will want to follow some tutorials for that scripting language and learn the basics.